# Reverse exe file compiled by pyinstaller

Tags: python, patch-reversing, decompile

I am trying to get python source code from only exe file compiled by pyinstaller.

I used the [pyinstxtractor.py](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor/) and got extracted folder.

And then what or how should I do?

Or could you explain other ways?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. It's not immediately clear what your want or where you are stuck. The project README (I have never personally used that project!) states: _The header of the pyc files are automatically fixed so that a Python bytecode decompiler will recognize it._ so it appears to me that you should simply run the output from your above tool through a Python byte code decompiler.

Comment: Hi, 0xC00000022L, THanks for your reply.
Yep, I changed the header usng HxD, and used uncompyle6. But in converting processing, I got error.

Comment: None of that is in your question, though. So what error did you get and by now we'd probably need the file. Also, did you try another bytecode decompiler?

Comment: Hi,  0xC0000022L.
I really want to get any help from someone, if possible, from you.
Can I upload or show you the file?

Comment: Yes. Please upload the file and also mention the exact error you get  here.

Comment: Hi, sudhackar. Thanks for your reply. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1huMpNj0sIrFqCeY0AEl8AwJq3E-A5hgj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the result extracted by pyinstxtractor.py.

Comment: and I worked with "convert" file, I inserted header of another pyc file (42 0D 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00) to the header of this file and then renamed as convert.pyc.   and I tried to decompyle using "uncompyle6 convert.pyc".    But I got error.